# Слитное/раздельное написание "несломимого"

Tags: частица-не

Никакими воздействиями не сломимый.

Является ли в данном случае слово "сломимый" причастием, и раздельное написание с не - нормативным при том, что оно имеет при себе зависимые слова?

P. S. Примеров употребления с раздельным написанием не нашёл, что и вызвало вопрос к жизни.

Answer (score 1):

Сломимый - **давно устаревшая форма**, в современном русском языке её нет.

"Словарь русского языка XVIII в."

> НЕСЛОМИ́МЫЙ, ая, ое. Стойкий, твердый, непоколебимый, несокрушимый. Несломи́мый, ..infragilis. ЛП 195. Мѣдное сердце. Жестокое, отважное, несломимое сердце против всякаго страху. Кнт. Соч. I 60. http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/14/slf06509.htm

Морфологический словарь утверждает, что это прилагательное: https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=118&s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8=1-

Причастной формы не существует, следовательно, и раздельного написания нет, только слитное. Видимо, повторяется история со словом непобедимый: это бывшее страдательное причастие (суффикс -им-), которое утратило признак действия и стало обозначать только признак предмета, то есть стало прилагательным. Без приставки не- оно не употребляется, как и ряд аналогичных слов: неугасимый, неиссякаемый, неистребимый, невредимый.

*Никем непобедимая. Никакими воздействиями несломимый*.

Comment: Такие слова необходимо заучить?

Comment: Зачем заучивать, если и так понятно, что они без НЕ не употребляются? Впрочем, можно и запомнить.